# Computing the PDF of a WishartMatrixDistribution. Is this a limitation in the PDF Mathematica function?

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm trying to compute the pdf of a wishart distribution.

Why does

```
PDF[WishartMatrixDistribution[10, IdentityMatrix[4]], 
 2*IdentityMatrix[4]]
```

not return a number? The output I get is exactly the same line of code... There are no error warnings, nothing.

Comment: I just changed the title to reflect the fact that the problem pertains to `WishartMatrixDistribution` and not to `WishartDistribution` - this may be misleading. Change it back if you are not comfortable with that.

Comment: I believe the matrix distributions do not work with `PDF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that `WishartMatrixDistribution` cannot be used with `PDF`. But you can use the `MultivariateStatistics` package:

```
Needs[ "MultivariateStatistics`"];
PDF[ WishartDistribution[ IdentityMatrix[4], 10], 2*IdentityMatrix[4] ]
```

> $\frac{1}{1\,814\,400\,e^4\,\pi^4}$

The definition for [`WishartDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/MultivariateStatistics/ref/WishartDistribution.html) is exactly the same as that for the [`WishartMatrixDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WishartMatrixDistribution.html) as far as I can see - but the parameterization is reverted.

Comment: As a further comment, PDF does not work with WishartMatrix not even when you sample from it and then plug the values into PDF[dist, x]. The documentation suggests a Series expansion, but for distributions without known functional forms - which Wishart and Inverse Wishart have. Also, the parametrisation is indeed reversed.

Comment: gwr, thanks for the answer. It seems to work now, but something seems off. Now, in the programme, when I use MultinormalDistribution or the MultivariateTDistribution, their names show in a different colour, as if they were spelled wrong... Do you have an idea of what's happening?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.  That is called *shadowing* and you can read up on it [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/HandleShadowingOfSymbolNames.html). Once you start with a fresh kernel and load the package first everything should be fine again.

Comment: That's the thing... I quit the kernel, and rebooted it, and I still get the same red colour...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. You need to load the package first before you use the symbol. There is more explanation in the link I sent you and has to do with `Contexts`.

Comment: GWR, I've read the link, but I'm not sure I understood correctly. So, now the MultinormalDistribution and MultivariateTDistribution are the functions which are used in the package MultivariateStatistics. Therefore, I can use them as before, even though their definition has been substituted

Comment: Also, I've tried the following: I quit the kernel, I put the loading of the package right before the evaluation of the first function using any Multivariate Distribution. However, I still get the red colouring of the MultinormalDistribution and MultivariateTDistribution...

Comment: Sorry, yes it's acceptable. thanks ;)